# Web Api Can I return a Data Object rather than a view model and also return references to sub objects without the whole object?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, viewmodel

So I'm currently building a Web API where on our Get Methods we used to be returning ViewModels which consisted of a specific subset of our actual data objects. The benefit of this was that we could pick and choose what all we wanted to return (Some objects had a lot of unneeded references). We've since found a way around creating endless binding models by using [JsonIgnore] on our data objects and are trying to figure out if we can do the same thing to our view models and cut out extra code.

So far it seems like with [JsonIgnore] we should be able to get rid of the need of returning ViewModels almost entirely except for the fact that we don't always want to be returning whole sub objects, but instead want to return the reference to the call to get the sub object if the client desires to.

Any ideas for workarounds without needing to build viewmodels over and over again for each data object?

Comment: For me you try to create some kind of "god" class which cover all possible scenarios. I think this is not very good approach. Why you can not use different models for different cases?

Comment: The reason we are trying to avoid ViewModels is just to cut down on code. It would be nice to not have to create ViewModels for every data object we have. It's not a necessity but I was just hoping to find some other way to do the project.

Comment: Small amount of code do not means good software. Usually trying to create classes which "do everything" lead to difficult to read(understand) and difficult to maintain code. It is ok to have own class for every model or viewmodel.